# What do the Facebook channelURL and appId do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});



  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
</script>
```

In the above code, what are the channelURL and appId here and why is the document object passed as a parameter when loading the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

`appId`: You have to create a Facebook App on Developers page if you have not already done so. When a Facebook app is created, it will have an `appId`. This is the `appId` you are asking about.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) you can read the following about channelURL:

> Specifies the URL of a custom URL channel file. This file must contain
>   a single script element pointing to the JavaScript SDK URL.

Comment: if im using comment box plugin why i need appId?

Comment: Because when you use Facebook API you have to specify the app where your commands are applicable. Facebook has a lot of Apps and it is not able to determine which app you are using without you specifying it using appId.

Comment: I am not familiar with comment plugin, so I do not know what does it mean "it worked" and why it worked. You have asked a question about facebook appId and channelURL and I have answered your question by sharing my knowledge about these data. If you still have questions, then you can ask them separately.

Comment: There is nothing about the channel url in that link